# Will it cost money if I just follow the tutorial at GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm fresh to GCP and i'm using my company's billing. But i'm not sure if I do those tutorial, it will cost money or not.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6e8Q.png)

So this is one of the tutorial about App Engine Quickstart. It will need to deploy an python app balabalabala.

My question is, all those quickstart tutorial, will they cost money?

Thanks for all your help!~

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODDLQ.png)

Comment: There are not enough details in your question to answer about costs. App Engine normally is very inexpensive but you can rack up a sizable bill if you do not know what you are doing. Google publishes pricing information. Research what you want to do and how much it will cost. Always assume there is a cost until you discover otherwise.

Comment: Talk to your boss and have him set up a project for you to practice in. Adding solid Google Cloud skills has value for most employers. Convince him to sponsor you. If he says no, then you should not be using a company account for personal usage. I would not risk my job for a few dollars of GCP services. Your other options are Qwiklabs or set up a Free Tier account with $300.00 in credits to start with.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers stated you can use a personal account linked to your credit card to get $300 starting credits or [use free resources](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits). Another option would be to use [Qwiklabs](https://www.qwiklabs.com/). Qwiklabs give you temporary credentials to Google Cloud Platform and Amazon Web Services, so you can learn the cloud using the real thing. To use these labs you have to purchase credits or use a promo code. A list of promo codes can be found [here](https://medium.com/@sathishvj/qwiklabs-free-codes-gcp-and-aws-e40f3855ffdb).

Comment: Yeah sure, but it has quota limitation and time limitiation, which measn it can be a temporary but not very much convenient solution for me. Thanks anyway~

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Platform (GCP) provides a free tier for [12-months with $300 credits](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) to spend, also in this documentation you can check the limits. Furthermore, you can spend this credits in any GCP product.

Comment: Sure thanks. I'm using the account my company gets for me. So I don't know whether i'm already in a free tier or not. I'll try to use the Google Cloud Training anyway.

Comment: Bear in mind that, tutorials are free but the resources that you may use for these tutorials if you cross the limits ([depending on the product](https://cloud.google.com/free/)) you have to pay for these resources.

Comment: OHHHH, Sure, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> > GCP Free Tier
> >     The Google Cloud Platform Free Tier gives you free resources to learn about Google Cloud Platform (GCP) services by trying them on your own. Whether you're completely new to the platform and need to learn the basics, or you're an established customer and want to experiment with new solutions, the GCP Free Tier has you covered.

The GCP Free Tier has two parts:

- List item

A 12-month free trial with $300 credit to use with any GCP services.
**Always Free, which provides limited access to many common GCP resources, free of charge.**

Comment: Sure thanks. I'm using the account my company gets for me. So I don't know whether i'm already in a free tier or not. I'll try to use the Google Cloud Training anyway.