# About Google Cloud Platform Console credit/debit billing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, credit-card, billing, trial

I've just created a Google Cloud Platform (for testing purposes only). It asked for my credit/debit card, it said it's completely free so I just fill in my debit card info. Then after that, when I go to the Billing Info tab, it said that I have 300$ in my account??? I mean what? Does it take from my debit card, still I've just checked my debit card money and it doesn't change yet (maybe tomorrow it will go down), but I'm super worried right now.

I want to ask:

1. Is this 300$ free? Or does it take from my debit card?
2. If I use some paid services here which use that 300$ cash, will it take from my debit card too? Am I free to use that 300$ during the free trial time without worrying about anything?
3. What happen after the free trial?

Comment: The $300.00 is a credit that will be applied to future billing. Google has good documentation of the free trial and upgraded accounts. https://cloud.google.com/free

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will it cost money if I just follow the tutorial at GCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58601833/will-it-cost-money-if-i-just-follow-the-tutorial-at-gcp)

Comment: Thank you. It does. I've already upvoted. I can't mark a comment as an answer.